# Shear force oscillating plate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

I would just like to know if get right the dynamics for the following system:
[image]

The bottom plate is oscillating and the upper plate is free to move. I expect the top plate to also start oscillating. My question is: will it be [oscillating due to the shear stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_stress#Shear_stress_in_fluids):

$$\tau_{xy}=\mu \frac{dv_x}{dy} \ ?$$

In other words, will this force from the fluid determine the oscillation of the upper plate?

Sorry if that's a weird question, just wanted to ensure I get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply because no other force can push things in the horizontal direction in this setup.